# Unable to play Gif image in iOS Keyboard extension with real device

Tags: swift, gif, swift3, ios10, custom-keyboard

Hi am developing a Emoji app with swift3 iOS 10. I have used a public library for playing the Gif files. It works perfectly in iOS simulators not in real device displaying an error message

> Program ended with exit code: 9

I don't know what is wrong in it.

used this [Library](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift)

My Code is

`let testGifImage = UIImage.gifImageWithName("giphy")
 cell.EmojiImage.image = testGifImage`

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am having the same problem :(

Comment: Does the debugger stop at a particular line, so you can see where the error happens? Is there any other message printed out?

Comment: @Dawan it's a memory issue. please compress the size of the file. and clear the gif/image at  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let cell = CollectionViewCell.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionCell
                cell.imageview.image = nil

Comment: @Ragul thanks that was it! the 40mb memory limit was causing the issue. Even after compressing the gifs I am still not able to view all gifs together in one view so I have created multiple views for containing several gifs each

Comment: i am having the same issue, if anybody has solved this? kindly share the solution here.